# I have a RabbitMQ container that has regularly "unexpected_frame" exceptions, what does that mean?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I have an application that is pushing data into RabbitMQ and then some other apps are subscribing to the different exchanges.

But recently, I keep having errors like this after a few hours:

```
2020-07-09 12:45:12.670 [error] <0.23578.1> Error on AMQP connection <0.23578.1> (172.18.0.5:48230 ->
172.18.0.3:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest', state: running), channel 6:                                                                                 
operation basic.publish caused a connection exception unexpected_frame:
 "expected content header for class 60, got non content"
2020-07-09 12:45:12.674 [info] <0.23578.1> closing AMQP connection <0.23578.1> (172.18.0.5:48230 ->
 172.18.0.3:5672, vhost: '/'
```

On the client side, I get messages like this:

```
"Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer,
code=505, text='UNEXPECTED_FRAME - expected content body, got non content body frame instead',
classId=60, methodId=40"
```

This is on a docker container.

What could this error be about?

Answer (score 0):

You are sharing a channel for concurrent publishing, use below code

```
 lock (ch) {  ch.BasicPublish();  }
```

Comment: can you explain the difference?

Comment: @Thomas did this solve your problem? I'm stumbling across the same error message when using this library with C++ Qt despite using a QMutex to lock the bit of code that publishes. If you have some tips and could provide them I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: @Spray'n'Pray, I haven't had a chance to sort this out. We've scaled up and started to use AWS services directly instead of running out own.